# Is there a paper explaining algorithm of tabletop recognition?

Tags: ros, tabletop-object-detector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to find papers that explain the algorithm and design of tabletop recognition, but I cannot find one.

Does anyone know if there's paper explaining the algorithm used in tabletop object recognition?Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51050/is-there-a-paper-explaining-algorithm-of-tabletop-recognition?/) by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1371 on 2012-12-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Tabletop object recognition could basically be divided into two kinds: textured object recognition and textureless object recognition. For textureless objects, people mainly use shape information extracted from point cloud (like that generated by Kinect). You can refer to [Correspondence Grouping](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/correspondence_grouping.php#correspondence-grouping) and  [Implicit Shape Model](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/implicit_shape_model.php#implicit-shape-model) presented by PCL. There are both good docs and open source codes. For textured object recognition, people mainly use feature points like SIFT or SURF extracted from images. You can refer to [MOPED](http://personalrobotics.ri.cmu.edu/projects/moped.php) which also contains paper and open source codes. In ICRA2011, there is a perception challenge origanized by WillowGarage. The champion of this challenge published a paper named "A Textured Object Recognition Pipeline for Color and Depth Image Data" in ICRA2012 which is also very enlightening.

Hope that helps.

---

Originally posted by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) with karma: 741 on 2012-12-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2012-12-26**:
Thank you~!